# How to reference embedded images from CSS?

Tags: c#, .net, css, embedded-resource

I have a CSS file that is embedded in my assembly. I need to set a background image for certain elements using this CSS file, and the image needs to be an embedded resource also. Is this possible? Is there any way I can reliably do this?

I ran into the problem when putting an existing stylesheet into this dll then realized images weren't showing up. I don't know of any way to make it work though because I would need to know the URL to the embedded image.

Has anyone done anything like this?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
<% = WebResource("image1.jpg") %>
```

You can use above statement inside your CSS file, and while you register your CSS with 
WebResourceAttribute, you can set "PerformSubstitution" to true

```
Default.css
body{
    background: <%=WebResource("xyz.jpg")%>
}



[assembly, WebResource("Default.css","text/css", PerformSubstitution=true)]
[assembly, WebResource("xyz.jpg","image/jpg")]
```

Comment: I found when using background-image rather than background I needed to wrap the WebResource server tag with url('').
E.g. 
background-image: url('<%=WebResource("xyz.jpg") %>');

Answer (score 6):

Just follow the following steps to refer a web resource as background Image in CSS

1. Refer Image URL as  "background: url('<%=WebResource("xyz.jpg")%>');" in following manner.

   ```
   Default.css
   body{
         background: url('<%=WebResource("xyz.jpg")%>');
       }
   ```
2. In AssemblyInfo.cs file register the CSS file with "PerformSubstitution=true" attribute in following manner

   ```
   [assembly, WebResource("Default.css","text/css", PerformSubstitution=true)]
   ```
3. Now again in AssemblyInfo.cs file register the image file as

   ```
   [assembly, WebResource("xyz.jpg","image/jpg")]
   ```
4. Right Click the Image File (xyz.jpg) and CSS File (Default.css) and click on Properties now select "Build Resource" option as "Embedded Resource".

and its done.
Happy Coding !!!

Answer (score 4):

Mine is a slight variation on the other suggestions but it works for my inline CSS within my ASP.NET page

1. Add the following entry to the AssemblyInfo.cs file - `[assembly: WebResource("MyImageFile.png", "image/png")]`
2. add the following code within the CSS to reference the embedded resource - `background-image: url('<%= Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(typeof(MyUserControl), "MyImageFile.png") %>')`

Answer (score 0):

What about exposing the resources through a Web service?
Such as in the CSS file, set `background: url( getImage.aspx?image=newyork.jpg )`?

Comment: This is a good idea except that the resource is embedded in our common library, not in a web app. So unfortunately this won't work for me in this situation.

Comment: Then, reference the common library from a new web app, which is solely responsible for pulling out embedded resources from the common library?